# Find overlap between two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables. They have the same structure except one has an extra column. I'd like to find out the number of instances there are where the records in just one of the columns, "address," are identical. In other words, I want to find the number of addresses that appear in both tables.

Comment: Can we see your table schema, some sample data, have you tried anything??

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of addresses in both tables, use `union all` and `count()`:

```
select count(distinct address)
from ((select address from table1) union all
      (select address from table2)
     ) t
```

If you want addresses that are present in both tables:

```
select address
from ((select address, 1 as in1, 0 as in2 from table1) union all
      (select address, 0 as in1, 1 as in2 from table2)
     ) t
group by address
having sum(in1) > 0 and sum(in2) > 0;
```

You can get the count using:

```
select count(*)
from (select address
      from ((select address, 1 as in1, 0 as in2 from table1) union all
            (select address, 0 as in1, 1 as in2 from table2)
           ) t
      group by address
      having sum(in1) > 0 and sum(in2) > 0
     ) a;
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  The OP wants the addresses that are in both tables.

Comment: @DanFarrell . . . I can see how that is a very reasonable interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to join the two tables and count the records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.address = t2.address
```

If you want to ignore duplicates, for example , '123 Main' appears once in table1, but twice in table2, the above query would count it twice, but if you only want to count it once for '123 Main', then use `DISTINCT` also:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(t1.address)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.address = t2.address
```

Answer (score 0):

what you're describing is an *inner* join, which for Mysql, is the default join.

Here's an example matching on numbers.  Note I limited the results to 5 for readability.  The example should extend well to strings, provided you can find a good way to actually match the strings.

```
mysql> create temporary table test.t1 ( i int unsigned not null );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> create temporary table test.t2 ( i int unsigned not null );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test.t1 select floor(rand() * 100) from mysql.user;
Query OK, 125 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 125  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select test.t1.i, test.t2.i from test.t1 inner join test.t2 on test.t1.i = test.t2.i limit 5;
+----+----+
| i  | i  |
+----+----+
|  2 |  2 |
|  2 |  2 |
| 24 | 24 |
| 24 | 24 |
| 11 | 11 |
+----+----+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```